# Seperate object per column in a datagrid row

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, datagrid, datatemplate

I have a datagrid from SCADA software that I am recreating in WPF by creating a custom user control that can be used for more use cases. I have an observable collection of type SettingRow that contains the data of ***one*** cell. The problem is that it is not containing the data of one cell.

If I have 10 items in my collection than I cannot see an seperate item in for example Row 1, Column 3. I see the same item in for example Row 1, Column 2. So in short: I see the same SettingRow object no matter what column I select in a row.

[image]

Every cell is an seperate setting object that is bound to an DataTemplateSelector to select the appropiate datatemplate to display the value (boolean as checkbox, string and value as textbox etc.)

I have created a DataGrid that has a templateselector based on the value in the SettingRow class. The datagrid's itemssource is currently bound to the ObservableCollection in my viewmodel. It works, I see every SettingRow in each cell per row, but I am quite sure that I am seeing the same SettingRow in each column which is not an seperate object that is independent of the object in the column before that one.

I've tried some solutions on StackOverflow with an observable collection inside an observable collection but I do not really get it to work.

Underneath is the class that is displayed in each row. Does this object get copied over to the next column? Or is the same object re-used in every column?

```
public class SettingRow : ObservableObject
{

    public int ID { get; set; }

    public object Value { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string Unit { get; set; }

}
```

My datagrid in XAML is declared and only has the Name property. The rest are added through the code.

```
<DataGrid x:Name="OverviewDataGridView" ItemsSource="{Binding SettingsCollection, Mode=TwoWay}" AutoGenerateColumns="True">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" Binding="{Binding Name}">

            </DataGridTextColumn>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
```

Below I am creating a column per phase. The 4 phases are simulated since I do not have actual data. Now, every SettingRow should be individually editable and I need to retrieve it from the ViewModel.

This is in the code behind.

```
public void GenerateColumns()
    {
        //Simulate 4 phases  and adding a column per phase!
        for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
        {
            DataGridTemplateColumn templateCol = new DataGridTemplateColumn();
            templateCol.Header = "Phase " + i;

            TemplateSelector templateSel = new TemplateSelector();
            templateSel.BooleanTemplate = this.Resources["BooleanTemplate"] as DataTemplate;
            templateSel.TextTemplate = this.Resources["TextTemplate"] as DataTemplate;

            templateCol.CellTemplateSelector = templateSel;

            this.OverviewDataGridView.Columns.Add(templateCol);
        }
```

}

The ViewModel is quite simple it creates some test data. Every SettingRow that is created is displayed in every column, but I think I see the same object in each

```
public class DynamicDataGridViewModel : ObservableObject
{
    private ObservableCollection<SettingRow> settingsCollection;
    public ObservableCollection<SettingRow> SettingsCollection
    {
        get { return settingsCollection; }
        set
        {
            settingsCollection = value;
            RaisePropertyChangedEvent("SettingsCollection");
        }
    }


    public DynamicDataGridViewModel()
    {
        SettingsCollection = new ObservableCollection<SettingRow>();
        SettingsCollection.Add(new SettingRow() { ID = 0, Name = "Phase Active", Value = true, Unit = "" });
        SettingsCollection.Add(new SettingRow() { ID = 1, Name = "Minimum phase duration", Value = +900, Unit = "s" });
        SettingsCollection.Add(new SettingRow() { ID = 2, Name = "Min Supply air temperature", Value = 50.0302, Unit = "C" });
    }
```

}

And lastly, my DataTemplateSelector. It only handles the value of the SettingRow and display the correct symbol (boolean = checkbox etc.)

```
public class TemplateSelector : DataTemplateSelector
{
    public DataTemplate BooleanTemplate { get; set; }

    public DataTemplate TextTemplate { get; set; }

    public SettingRow Content { get; set; }

    public override DataTemplate SelectTemplate(object item, DependencyObject container)
    {
        ContentPresenter presenter = container as ContentPresenter;
        DataGridCell cell = presenter.Parent as DataGridCell;
        SettingRow row = (cell.DataContext as SettingRow); 

        if(row != null && row.Value != null)
        {
            this.Content = row;

            switch (Type.GetTypeCode(row.Value.GetType()))
            {
                case TypeCode.Boolean:
                    return BooleanTemplate;
                default:
                    return TextTemplate;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT:

Templates for the columns below

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="BooleanTemplate">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="2">
                <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding Value}"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>

        <DataTemplate x:Key="TextTemplate">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="2">
            <TextBox Height="25" MinWidth="70" FontSize="14">
                <TextBox.Text>
                    <MultiBinding StringFormat="{}{0} {1}">
                        <Binding Path="Value" Mode="TwoWay"/>
                        <Binding Path="Unit"  Mode="TwoWay"/>
                    </MultiBinding>
                </TextBox.Text>
            </TextBox>
        </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
```

What I need is a DataGrid bound to an observable collection. Which has dynamic amount of columns (represents an phase) and I need one SettingRow in every column and it to be editable per object. So that I can for example set the visibility of the Phase Duration setting in the Levelling phase to invisible.

EDIT 2:

What I have in mind is to use a observable collection inside an observable collection like the snippet below this way I can represent my data as the columns in each row. This way I can access every row and column individual object.:

```
 private ObservableCollection<ObservableCollection<SettingRow>> items;
    public ObservableCollection<ObservableCollection<SettingRow>> ItemsSourceOfDataGrid
    {
        get { return items; }
        set
        {
            items = value;
            RaisePropertyChangedEvent("ItemsSourceOfDataGrid")
        }
    }
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT: So after looking over the comments and what you want, the EASIEST thing to do is to define all of your row names and then have the `ObservableCollection` be a collection of columns instead of rows. If you want to go the crazy route of both dynamic rows and columns, well these can get you started:

https://svitla.com/blog/grid-with-dynamic-number-of-rows-and-columns-part-1
https://svitla.com/blog/grid-with-dynamic-number-of-rows-and-columns-part-2

The source Github: https://github.com/IReznykov/Blog

So, the way to do it with dynamic columns instead is pretty straight forward.

Just to reiterate:

Make sure your `RaisePropertyChangedEvent` is added to the items in your model. This will allow them to be changed dynamically inside your `SettingsCollection`. Also, the XAML portion of your `DataGrid` needs to be setup in a certain way to work with this.

```
public class SettingColumn : ObservableObject
{
    public int _PhaseNumber;
    public int PhaseNumber
    {
        get { return _PhaseNumber; }
        set
        {
            PhaseNumber = value;
            RaisePropertyChangedEvent("PhaseNumber");
        }
    }

    public object _MinPhaseDuration;
    public object MinPhaseDuration
    {
        get { return _Value; }
        set
        {
            Value = value;
            RaisePropertyChangedEvent("Value");
        }
    }

    public string _MinSupplyAirTemp;
    public string MinSupplyAirTemp
    {
        get { return _MinSupplyAirTemp; }
        set
        {
            MinSupplyAirTemp = value;
            RaisePropertyChangedEvent("MinSupplyAirTemp");
        }
    }

    // The rest of your row labels here.
    .
    .
    .
```

Hope this edit helps get you going. Again, dynamic rows AND columns is a pain. Save yourself some headache and define either all your row labels or your column labels.

Comment: First of all, thanks for the response! I was actually expecting an answer like this, but you've misunderstood. I need a seperate actual class of SettingRow for each column. Currently I have the same class for every column, if I change the property Value in column 1 it changes everywhere. I am currently experimenting with the SettingRow class that contains an custom class that implements BindingList and ITypedList so that the class automatically generates the columns based on that list, but I am not sure wether this is the correct way.

Comment: Please rephrase your question then and create a graphic that shows EXACTLY what you need then. Regardless, you still need `RaisePropertyChangedEvent` for each variable holding information for the `DataGrid`. I just reread the last line of your question and I still do not see how my answer does not solve that. I can create that on my PC right now and it works.

Comment: I have rephrased my question and the first picture has been updated to give you a more clear idea of what my goal is. In regards to your solution, I assume that when RaisePropertyChangedEvent is called that every column in the particular row (where the SettingRow object is in) is changed with the new value. Is it?

Comment: I have tried your solution, just to be sure. When I change a value in a row and column, all columns in that row change in value aswell, that is the problem I am facing. I am sorry if I explained it a little off, it was quite hard for me to explain this problem.

Comment: You must have something wrong someplace. Generally, if you define each row explicitly and map that to a variable in your model, then changing a cell should not affect any other cell. Are you actually trying to have explicit rows with dynamic columns? Also, are you saying that changing a single cell is causing all the other cells to also change?

Comment: Yes, changing a single cell in one row causes the others to change aswell.

Comment: Ok, so lets say you are changing a cell and the value is X. Do all the other cells then become the same value X?

Comment: Yes, only in the same row because all of them are the same SettingRow object.

Comment: Ok, I think I see the issue here. Are the columns suppose to be dynamic and the row labels static? Or are their dynamic row labels also? Essentially, are the row labels always going to be the same?

Comment: My columns are defined based on the phases I receive, so the columns are indeed dynamic. The row's are also dynamic (bound to ItemsSource). The text inside the cell is dynamic, if it is an boolean I represent it as an checkbox, if it's an progress I'll show that as progressbar which is defined by templates controlled by the template selector. What do you mean by Row Labels?

Comment: Row labels are the names all the way to the left for each row such as in ""Minimum Phase duration" and "Min Supply Air Temperature" and etc. Are those ALWAYS the same or will they change?

Comment: They are defined in a list, they could change indeed.

Comment: Ok, I understand what you want. Generally, when you have data in a spreadsheet, it is poor practice to have dynamic labels on both rows and columns. However if this is what you need, I can work something out for you. You have several moving parts and need to break things out. I will create an answer for you on how I would do this.

Comment: That would be awesome! Would really appreciate that. I've been testing a lot and couldn't get it to work.

Comment: One question, I have sketched some stuff out, but have a quick question. Does the number of Phases change? Is there a maximum number of Phases?

Comment: The phases are indeed dynamic, there could be 10 phases but also 50. It's highly unlikely to go over 20 though, I think you ask this due to performance? But indeed, the phases could change.

Comment: I ask because it will determine how the columns can be handled. I cannot take the time to write the whole thing, but I will try to give you an answer to get you in the right direction. It will basically requiring you to create a custom template for the datagrid.

Comment: How man possible rows could there be? I am trying to see if we can do this without an overly complicated dynamic datagrid or datatable converter.

Comment: Edited my answer and gave you some links.

Comment: Thank you for all the help. Ultimately I have been converting everything into an datatable. Although not the solution is was really seeking for but helped me out and works now. The below solution converts it into a datatable and selects the DataTemplate when auto generating.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25643765/wpf-datagrid-databind-to-datatable-cell-in-celltemplates-datatemplate

I've been trying your solution and that worked aswell, although it was not really displaying really well since I can have a string that is really long and that would really mess up the looks.

Comment: Glad I was able to help. Just so you know, you can always create methods that can size your `DataGrid` or `ListView` headers dynamically based on content.