# WPF DataGrid Column Template for custom object

Tags: wpf, datatable, binding, datagrid

I have a WPF `DataGrid` bound to a `DataTable`. The `DataTable` has columns containing strings and columns containing custom objects (`Requirement`):

```
public class PdfFormData
{
    public string SupplierName { get; set; }
    public List<Requirement> Requirements = new List<Requirement>();

    public class Requirement
    {
        public string ID { get; set; }
        public string SupplierStatus { get; set; }
        public string SupplierComment { get; set; }
        public string OEMStatus { get; set; }
    }
}
```

I'm adding the columns to the `DataGrid` with this loop:

```
PHDataGrid.ItemsSource = dataSet.Tables["ReqIfTable"].DefaultView;
PHDataGrid.Columns.Clear();
foreach (DataColumn dataColumn in dataSet.Tables["ReqIfTable"].Columns)
{
   if(dataColumn.DataType == typeof(ReqForms.PdfFormData.Requirement))
   {
      DataGridTemplateColumn dgColumn = new DataGridTemplateColumn();
      dgColumn.Header = dataColumn.ColumnName;
      dgColumn.CellTemplate = (DataTemplate)FindResource("dgTemplateRequirement");

      dgColumn.CanUserSort = true;
      dgColumn.IsReadOnly = true;
      PHDataGrid.Columns.Add(dgColumn);
   }
   else
   {
      DataGridTextColumn dgColumn = new DataGridTextColumn();
      dgColumn.Header = dataColumn.ColumnName;
      Binding dgBinding = new Binding(dataColumn.ColumnName);
      dgColumn.Binding = dgBinding;
      dgColumn.CanUserSort = true;
      dgColumn.IsReadOnly = true;
      PHDataGrid.Columns.Add(dgColumn);
   }
}
```

And I have defined a template for showing my `Requirement` objects:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="dgTemplateRequirement">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Requirement.SupplierStatus}" />
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Requirement.SupplierComment}" />
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Requirement.OEMStatus}" />
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
</Window.Resources>
```

The `Binding` to the `Requirement` properties (`SupplierStatus`, `SupplierComment`, ...) is not working and stays empty. How can I bind to the properties of my custom object that is stored in the `DataTable`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bindings do not work, because the `DataContext` of the the templated cell is a `DataRowView`.

You can either create a converter as in this [related post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25643765/wpf-datagrid-databind-to-datatable-cell-in-celltemplates-datatemplate) or just access the members directly with an indexer binding path, where `requirement` is the name of your column in the `DataTable`, e.g.:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Row[requirement].SupplierStatus}" />
```

I set the `DataContext` of the `StackPanel` to the `Requirement` object, so it is even easier to bind.

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="dgTemplateRequirement">
   <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" DataContext="{Binding Row[requirement]}">
      <TextBlock Text="{Binding SupplierStatus}" />
      <TextBlock Text="{Binding SupplierComment}" />
      <TextBlock Text="{Binding OEMStatus}" />
   </StackPanel>
</DataTemplate>
```

Comment: The columns of my table are created at runtime so I cannot access them by name, but the converter works fine.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution in this post:
[WPF DataGrid - Databind to DataTable cell in CellTemplates DataTemplate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25643765/wpf-datagrid-databind-to-datatable-cell-in-celltemplates-datatemplate)
You have to use a converter to reach from the table to the actual object.